# Bulk create Nodes from SQL

Tags: 7, database

I have an ASP.NET website using MySQL. 
1 table('books') holds more than 1000 books, each record has unique ID, name, writer etc.
I want to import those books into Drupal. I'm planning to create Custom Fields(name, writer etc) for a New Content Type.

Is it possible to create Nodes like this from SQL file?

Answer (score 3):

Possible, yes.  Recommended, no.  I do a lot of importing from outside sources, and would *never* entertain using direct SQL `INSERT` statements.

I would export your existing database in another format, and pursue one of standard approaches.

The easiest is probably [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds).  In your case, I would export as CSV, and then use the CVS imported built into feeds.  Based on your description, it sounds like you have a one-to-one mapping, and the CSV importer is good for this.

The [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module can also handle moving data from one source into Drupal.

A more robust solution would be to create a custom importer, build up a `$node`, and then use [`node_save`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7).  There are a lot of nuances with this, and this is not a good approach unless you are familiar with the Drupal API already.

Comment: +1 for the Migrate module.  It works beautifully with many SQL implementations.

Comment: I have used Feeds module before, that was for the Ecommerce products Bulk insert. I guess it works the same idea, if that doesnt work then I go with Migrate module, thx